# How to append image in global array?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to append images in an array and want to display them in a window using tkinter. I have yet written a sample code to insert just one image but i am getting issue with global variable defined.

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np

app=Tk()
app.title("Slideshow")
frame= Canvas (bg='black', height=600, width=1000)
global img
img1 = np.append(img,PhotoImage(file='images/1.png'))
frame.create_image(800,50,anchor=NE,image=img1)

frame.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Error I am encountering is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Maha Waqar/PycharmProjects/SlideShow/1st.py", line 10, in <module>
    img1 = np.append(im,PhotoImage(file='images/1.png'))
NameError: name 'img' is not defined
```

I have tried to play with global variable in may ways so that it may work but hard luck. Any suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciable.

Comment: You did not initialize `img`.

Comment: I have written "global img". What is the other way of initializing?

Comment: It needs to have a value.

Comment: @MahaWaqar that is simply a directive that is not necessary (and indeed, pointless) in the global scope already, that says "the name `img` is global". It doesn't create any lists...

Comment: So how to create img list? I may be wrong in syntax. A clarified answer with code will be highly appreciable

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you try to use `numpy` and `np.append()`. But broblem is so basis that you shouldn't even ask.

You have to create array first

```
img = np.array(PhotoImage)
```

and then you can append

```
img1 = np.append(img, ...)
```

---

But there is next problem - you can't use array with `create_image()`. You have to use single image.

```
img = np. array()

single_image = PhotoImage(file='images/1.png')

img1 = np.append(img, single_image)

frame.create_image(..., image=single_image)
```

---

Instead of `numpy` you can use standard list

```
img_list = []

single_image = PhotoImage(file='images/1.png')

img_list.append(single_image)

frame.create_image(..., image=single_image)
```

or use index to get image from list - ie. `img_list[-1]` gives last image from list

```
img_list = []

img_list.append(PhotoImage(file='images/1.png'))

frame.create_image(..., image=img_list[-1])
```